# How to change the default docker subnet - Docker for Windows, Visual studio 2017?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

As Docker uses 172.xx.xx.xx subnet for container networking and this subnet is not available for docker in my environment under some circumstances (for example because the network already uses this subnet when I am connected to other VPN), I should configure Docker to use a different subnet.

Otherwise I cannot debug  app locally in Docker mode in Visual studio on my machine when connected to that VPN.

What is the easiest way to do that in Windows10/Visual studio 2017 environment?